# Google Maps API responsive searchbox

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design, responsive

I have a full screen Google Maps Div, and I added an Input to be used as a searchbox. This is the code:

```
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;

}
.container, .container > div, .container > div #map {
    height: inherit;
}
.mapcanvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:0px; /* adjust top margin to your header height */
}
</style>
<body onload="initializeMap()">
            <div id="map" class="mapcanvas"></div>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the place you are looking for" type="text" id="input_location">
    </div>        
</body>
<script>
      function initializeMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    {  
                      tilt:0
                      ,center:new google.maps.LatLng(41.946, 13.499)
                      ,zoom:7
                      ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                       ,mapTypeControlOptions: {
                          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
                        }
                    }
                );
                const input = document.getElementById("input_location");
                const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

      }
    </script>
```

When I open this page on the smartphone, the searchBox is very, very small.
How can I control the size of this? I tried with Bootstrap classes `class="form-control form-control-lg"` and with `style="font-size:36px"` but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not directly related to Google maps API.
It was related to a web forward that uses an iframe tag.
This causes the mobile browser to render the desktop version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the responsiveness of your webpage. A mobile browser is rendering your website as a desktop website.

To eliminate this problem simply insert

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the `<head>...</head>` of your homepage.

#### Output

[image]

There is also a suggestion for you. If your page looks like what you have shared above then make some changes to it.

Put the `<script>...</script>` inside the `<body>...</body>`and don't forget to include `<html>`, `<head>` etc to your webpage.

Comment: I have the meta tag and all the other tags (html, head, body, ecc.) already but the input box is very small on Safari on iPhone. If I run the page in Chrome on the PC and I select smartphone in the developers tools, it appears bigger...

Comment: Have you included `meta name=''viewport"`? If yes then share the screenshots.